# Software logic for calculating crc in a bootloader application

Tags: c, embedded, bootloader, crc

I found a file to check crc of an incoming application via some interface and the program is as follows:

```
#define CRC16POLY   0x1021  
#define PKTLEN_128  128

typedef struct Crc16Data {
    uint16_t currentCrc;    //!< Current CRC value.
} crc16_data_t;

void crc16_init(crc16_data_t * crc16Config)
{
    // initialize running crc and byte count
    crc16Config->currentCrc = 0;
}

void crc16_update(crc16_data_t * crc16Config, const uint8_t * src, uint32_t lengthInBytes)
{
    uint32_t crc = crc16Config->currentCrc;

    uint32_t j;
    for (j=0; j < lengthInBytes; ++j)
    {
        uint32_t i;
        uint32_t byte = src[j];
        crc ^= byte << 8;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            uint32_t temp = crc << 1;
            if (crc & 0x8000)
            {
                temp ^= 0x1021;
            }
            crc = temp;
        }
    }

    crc16Config->currentCrc = crc;
}

void crc16_finalize(crc16_data_t * crc16Config, uint16_t * hash)
{
    *hash = crc16Config->currentCrc;
}
```

I understood that it is simple crc software logic that doesnot involve any hardware generated crc mechanism to calculate crc of an incoming application and it is just counting the bytes of the application and adding them and placing them right? Can anyone explain what is happening inside `void crc16_update(crc16_data_t * crc16Config, const uint8_t * src, uint32_t lengthInBytes)` function?
And in one of the files `crc16update(....)` function is called as follows:

```
crc16_update(&crcInfo,buffer,PKTLEN_128);
```

where in another functions `crcInfo`,buffer information is found from

```
static void read_bytes(uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t byteCount)
{
    uint32_t currentBytesRead = 0;

    while(currentBytesRead != byteCount)
    {
        if (readOffset != writeOffset)
        {
            buffer[currentBytesRead++] = callback_buffer[readOffset++];
            readOffset &= XMODEM_BUFLEN - 1;
        }
    }
}

static int read_packet(uint8_t *buffer, uint8_t idx)
{
    uint8_t  seq[2],crc1,crc2;
    uint16_t  crc16, verify16;
    crc16_data_t crcInfo;

    read_bytes(seq,2);

    read_bytes(buffer,PKTLEN_128);
    crc16_init(&crcInfo);
    crc16_update(&crcInfo,buffer,PKTLEN_128);
    crc16_finalize(&crcInfo,&verify16);

    read_bytes(&crc1,1);
    read_bytes(&crc2,1);
    crc16  = ((uint16_t)crc1 << 8)|crc2;

    if ((crc16 != verify16) || (seq[0] != idx) || (seq[1] != (uint8_t) ((~(uint32_t)idx)&0xff)))
        return(-1);

    return(0);
}
```

What is happening inside the function `void crc16_update(crc16_data_t * crc16Config, const uint8_t * src, uint32_t lengthInBytes)` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: `crc16_update` is pushing bytes into the crc calculation engine.   That engine is the two while loops in the middle of the function.  If you want to know that THAT works, you should spend some more time on google.

Comment: It is "updating the CRC" the clue is in the name - what don't you understand specifically?  Did you want to know _how_ it worked - i.e. the theory, rather then _what_ it does?  Every byte of data received modifies the CRC in `crc16Config->currentCrc`, the function allows that to be calculated _as the data arrives_ in units of arbitrary length rather than having to wait until all has arrived and calculate in one chunk - though you could do that too if you had sufficient buffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
    crc ^= byte << 8;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        uint32_t temp = crc << 1;
        if (crc & 0x8000)
        {
            temp ^= 0x1021;
        }
        crc = temp;
    }
```

updates the CRC with the byte. It simulates running a linear feedback shift register, whose state is the value of `crc`. That could can be written more compactly possibly making it easier to see what's going on:

```
    crc ^= byte << 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        crc = crc & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc << 1;
```

The high bit of `crc` determines whether or not to exclusive-or the polynomial `0x1021` with the register, after the register is shifted up one bit, with that high bit dropping off the end.

To learn more about how this implementation is arrived at, you should read [Ross William's CRC tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt).